# Is this the correct command for logging MySQL import errors only into a file?

Tags: mysql, linux, bash

I have a long-running MySQL dump import that I've just started and I believe it's going to throw some warnings/errors that I want to capture.

Is this the correct command for capturing all error output from the MySQL dump import into a file without outputting standard output to the screen or a file? I just want the errors and warnings to go into dumperrors.log

```
mysql --verbose -u root -p database1 < database1dump.sql >/dev/null 2>/home/dumperrors.log
```

Comment: Should work fine if  you have access to /home/dumperrors.log

Comment: @MrJ : I would be surprised if you had write access to `/home`. Can't you think of a more sensible location for the log file?

Comment: I'd recommend `/tmp` instead of just dumped in `/home`. If the warnings are reported on STDERR you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks, I set up a test dump file full of errors to test with and it's working as expected :-)